# AWS Node SDK async SNS.publish.promise() does not send SNS message immediately (from Lambda)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I understand when we use the .promise method with an AWS resource (eg SNS.publish) the AWS resource should be called immediately, the response resolving/rejecting the returned promise.

On my tests with SNS.publish the SNS message does not get sent until the promise is awaited.

I am using node within a Lambda function.

Example code:

```
'use strict';

const SNS = require('aws-sdk/clients/sns')
const client = new SNS()

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    let requestParams = {
      Message: JSON.stringify(event),
      TopicArn: `arn:aws:sns:XXXX`,
    };
    let publishPromise = client.publish(requestParams).promise();

    //pause for an amount of time
    console.log('before pause');
    var start = Date.now()
    var now = start;
    while (now - start < 10000) {
      now = Date.now();
    }
    console.log('after pause');

    await publishPromise;

  } catch (e) {
    throw (e);
  }
};
```

In my case the SNS triggers an SQS queue that triggers a target Lambda, I am using the target Lambda's cloudwatch logs to judge whether the SNS message is sent as soon as SNS.publish is invoked, or later when the await is called (comparing target Lambda's log timestamps to the above Lambda's).

The pause section in the above code pauses the script before awaiting the promise allowing us to more clearly see when the SNS message gets sent. In the above example a 10 second pause is used, any pause period gives me the same results, the target Lambda receives the messages after the await is called, not when SNS.publish is called.

Am I missing something? The SNS request to publish a message should go out immediately when SNS.publish is invoked, not held back until the await, what I am observing kind of defeats the purpose of async.. I must be missing something simple here..

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis in await publishPromise()

Comment: @Carlo thanks but I don't think that's it, client.publish returns a promise, not an async function, if awaiting an async function you need the parenthesis but a promise object they are not needed? Also I don't believe this is where the issue lies, what I am seeing is the SNS message does not get processed by the AWS SNS service until we await the promise, which suggests promisifying the invocation of client.publish is not initiating it asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone else here, the behaviour is as expected. `publishPromise` is a Promise, not a function, so it is called with a `.then`

The code should be

```
publishPromise.then(
  (result) => console.log("SNS published with",result),
  (err) => console.log("Error publishing SNS", err)
)
```

But the real issue is that it's not a real Promise and does not hold up your Lambda when called. It sails right past and will probably finish and close before the SNS is actually published

Comment: So if we wanted to send an SNS out, have it actually sent, do some other logic, then await to make sure the SNS is sent before the Lambda function returns, we could do:

`let requestParams = { Message: JSON.stringify(event), TopicArn: XXXX,}; let publishPromise = client.publish(requestParams).promise(); publishPromise.then(); //do other logic; await publishPromise;`

SNS maybe a bad example AWS request because it probably returns very quickly and does not need the async flow, but for other requests like a Lambda syncronous request it might be important..